# Pandas: How to group by a particular column value, and then expand the number of columns to includes other values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

Say that I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Column 1     Column 2
a                    value1
a                    value2
a                    value3
b                    value4
b                    value5
c                    value6
d                    value7
d                    value8
d                    value9
d                    value10
```

I would like to group up all unique values in Column 1, and then expand the number of columns in column two so that it includes all the the values of Column 2, here's what that'll look like

```
Column 1     Column 2                  Column 2_1            Column 2_2            Column 2_3
a                    value1                    value2                    value3                    None
b                    value4                    value5                    None                      None
c                    value6                    None                      None                      None                      
d                    value7                    value8                   value9                   value10
```

If it is easier, concatenating the values in column 2 so that they're all in one column will also work for me since that is the final result I need.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: askdocsDataComm5 = askdocsDataComm4.groupby('id')['body'].apply(','.join)